# WPF MVVM button enabled state

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am in the process of learning WPF using the MVVM pattern, which is going well overall, however I have one issue with the enabled/disabled state of some buttons.

I have 3 buttons whose `IsEnabled` state should follow this:

```
App Startup:  enabled | disabled | disabled 
Click first:  disabled | enabled | disabled 
Click second: enabled | disabled | enabled 
Click third:  enabled | disabled | enabled
```

All of the buttons have a separate Command attached to them, so I know when they have been clicked. However I'm not sure how to relay the interaction back to the window to set the `IsEnabled` state of the other button controls.

I know how to do it with events and code behind, but I am trying to keep this as close to pure MVVM as possible. I also know I could have some properties on my ViewModel that could be bound to the `IsEnabled` property of the buttons, but that seems a little inelegant to me (but I could be wrong!).

Could someone please give me some suggestions to how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use data binding here, so boolean properties on your view model that change when the commands are invoked and to which your buttons bind their `IsEnabled` property, declaratively in the XAML.

This allows you to test the logic very easily, independently of the view. You can instantiate your view model, invoke the appropriate method on the view model, and then inspect the appropriate boolean properties.

You might also wish to consider an [MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx), as commanding has limitations.

Comment: That was one of my solutions, but it didn't seem very elegant to me, hence why I thought there might be a better way to do it, however your suggestion works well. As for a framework, I know I need to learn one, but that will depend on what my job chooses, so I am just working with the basics for the time being.